# Integrate Google Teachable Machine Model to Java application

Tags: java, image-processing, deep-learning

I made an image model with https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com, which classifies simple 
standardized pictograms as I need this in my application but I didn't manage to import it to my java application. I tried everything from .h5 import via Deeplearning4j (unsupported) to fighting around with Tensorflow and savedModel. Other export-formats are Tensorflow.js and Tensorflow Lite.

My attempt to train a model manually in python was too complex for my current deeplearning skills and never worked as good as the teachable machine.

My program has to classify the known GHS-pictograms from images (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Harmonized_System_of_Classification_and_Labelling_of_Chemicals)

What should I do? Is there another way to integrate the model or maybe is there a simpler way than deeplearning for this simple thing?

Comment: please provide links and references. You do  want to be thorough in detailing your question, otherwise people will not bother. trying to figure out what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: you have an classifying model built in one server or app, and want to ask it questions from your java Application??

Comment: Sorry, I tried to clearify the question. 
My primary question is if there is a way to integrate the generated model in a java application, but I'm open to other approaches to this problem If someone knows one.

Answer (score 0):

First Export your model as `SavedModel`.
[image]

Then you can use ML Libraries to read it.

For Example:-

- [DLJ](https://djl.ai/)

Example code (Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62419161/17022570)):-

```
Criteria<Image, Classifications> criteria =
    Criteria.builder()
        .setTypes(Image.class, Classifications.class)
        .optModelUrls("https://example.com/squeezenet.zip")
        .optTranslator(ImageClassificationTranslator
               .builder().addTransform(new ToTensor()).build())
        .build();

try (ZooModel<Image, Classification> model = ModelZoo.load(criteria);
        Predictor<Image, Classification> predictor = model.newPredictor()) {
    Image image = ImageFactory.getInstance().fromUrl("https://myimage.jpg");
    Classification result = predictor.predict(image);
}
```