# Java Tensorflow + Keras Equivalent of model.predict()

Tags: java, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

In python you can simply pass a numpy array to `predict()` to get predictions from your model. What is the equivalent using Java with a `SavedModelBundle`?

### Python

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  # layers go here
])
model.compile(...)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(x_test_maxabs) # <= This line
```

### Java

```java
SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load(path, "serve");
model.predict() // ????? // What does it take as in input? Tensor?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TensorFlow Python automatically convert your NumPy array to a `tf.Tensor`. In TensorFlow Java, you manipulate tensors directly.

Now the `SavedModelBundle` does not have a `predict` method. You need to obtain the session and run it, using the `SessionRunner` and feeding it with input tensors.

For example, based on the next generation of TF Java (https://github.com/tensorflow/java), your code endup looking like this (note that I'm taking a lot of assumptions here about `x_test_maxabs` since your code sample does not explain clearly where it comes from):

```java
try (SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load(path, "serve")) {
    try (Tensor<TFloat32> input = TFloat32.tensorOf(...);
        Tensor<TFloat32> output = model.session()
            .runner()
            .feed("input_name", input)
            .fetch("output_name")
            .run()
            .expect(TFloat32.class)) {

        float prediction = output.data().getFloat();
        System.out.println("prediction = " + prediction);
    }        
}
```

If you are not sure what is the name of the input/output tensor in your graph, you can obtain programmatically by looking at the signature definition:

```java
model.metaGraphDef().getSignatureDefMap().get("serving_default")
```

Comment: I had to upgrade to TF 2.x to get `model.metaGraphDef().getSignatureDefMap().get("serving_default")` but other than that it worksed!

Answer (score 4):

You can try Deep [Java Library (DJL)](https://djl.ai).

DJL internally use Tensorflow java and provide high level API to make it easy fro inference:

```
Criteria<Image, Classifications> criteria =
    Criteria.builder()
        .setTypes(Image.class, Classifications.class)
        .optModelUrls("https://example.com/squeezenet.zip")
        .optTranslator(ImageClassificationTranslator
               .builder().addTransform(new ToTensor()).build())
        .build();

try (ZooModel<Image, Classification> model = ModelZoo.load(criteria);
        Predictor<Image, Classification> predictor = model.newPredictor()) {
    Image image = ImageFactory.getInstance().fromUrl("https://myimage.jpg");
    Classification result = predictor.predict(image);
}
```

Checkout the github repo: https://github.com/awslabs/djl

There is a blogpost: https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-pneumonia-from-chest-x-ray-images-e02bcf705dd6

And the demo project can be found: https://github.com/aws-samples/djl-demo/blob/master/pneumonia-detection/README.md

Answer (score 0):

In `0.3.1` API:

```kotlin
val model: SavedModelBundle = SavedModelBundle.load("path/to/model", "serve")

val inputTensor = TFloat32.tesnorOf(..)

val function: ConcreteFunction = model.function(Signature.DEFAULT_KEY)
val result: Tensor = function.call(inputTensor) // u can cast to type you expect, a type of returning tensor can be checked by signature: model.function("serving_default").signature().toString()
```

After you got a result Tensor of any subtype, you can iterate over its values. In my example, I had a `TFloat32` with shape `(1, 56)`, so I found max value by `result.get(0, idx)`